# Memory Efficiency in Tree Node values being stored as Dictionaries

Tags: c#, memory-management, data-structures, tree, hashmap

I am trying to make a non-binary, unbalanced Tree data structure where each node has an int value to identify it's type in a predetermined set of values.

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    Vector3 direction;
    int type;
    TreeNode<T>[] children;
    int childCount;
}
```

This is being used to hold data for a procedurally generated tree-like structure in a game I am making, so there may be sections where a branch will extend in such a way that it could be simplified (i.e a long string of nodes with identical direction, forming one long branch).

So what If I condense a sequence of nodes into one node and have a dictionary defining non-default types at certain points.

```
public class CondensedTreeNode<T> : TreeNode<T>
{
    Vector3 direction;
    Dictionary<Integer,Integer> type = new Dictionary<Integer,Integer>();
    TreeNode<T>[] children;
    int size;
    int childCount;
}
```

I'm wondering if this will make things any more efficient in terms of performance and memory.

If not, is there any data structure that would be more efficient than using a tree?

Comment: It may make it more compact as far as memory goes in the best case, but it will almost definitely make your code more difficult to understand/ maintain and debug. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Your big memory hit is that array of `TreeNode` references. Allocation overhead for an array is on the order of 50 bytes. A `Dictionary<K,V>` is going to cost you 100+ bytes of allocation overhead. As far as memory efficiency is concerned, you'd be better off using something like a [Left child right sibling binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) to represent your tree.